# Why is one way of generating binary sequences faster than another?

Tags: haskell

I want to generate all of the possible binary sequences of length n as lists. I've come up with two ways of doing this. I'd prefer the second, since it seems easier to read, but I don't know why it's significantly slower than the first.

```
bin_seqs_1 :: Int -> [[Int]]
bin_seqs_1 n = iterate add_bit [[]] !! n
    where add_bit seqs = [b : seq | seq <- seqs, b <- [-1,1]]

bin_seqs_2 :: Int -> [[Int]]
bin_seqs_2 n = sequence $ replicate n [-1,1]

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show $ bin_seqs_2 23
```

When I compile with optimization and run with bin_seqs_1 (redirecting the output to /dev/null), it takes 13 seconds. With bin_seqs_2, it takes 29 seconds.

Why is the second method so much slower?

EDIT:
So it has to do with the implementation of [sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/Control-Monad.html#sequence). If I redefine sequence to evaluate the tail of the list first, then the head, the performance is comparable to bin_seqs_1

```
bin_seqs_3 n = sequence $ replicate n [-1,1]
    where sequence ms = foldr k (return []) ms
          k m m' = do { xs <- m'; x <- m; return (x:xs) }
```

But I still don't understand why, in the "k" function, evaluating xs then x is so much faster than evaluating x then xs (as is done in Control.Monad).

Comment: Just FYI: `replicateM` for `sequence $ replicate` and `print` for `putStrLn $ show`.

Comment: did you try substituting the definition of `sequence`, to see the bind-based code to which it reduces?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but `bin_seqs_1` runs in constant memory, and not `bin_seqs_2`. If you transpose the list comprehension (`[b : seq | b <- [-1,1], seq <- seqs]`), it behaves like `bin_seqs_2`. You can get slightly faster, and maybe more idiomatic code, by rewriting `add_bit = concatMap (\s -> [-1:s, 1:s])`.

Answer (score 1):

This is partial answer to the part "Why is the second method so much slower?"

When in doubt of performance of list fusion, use coredump, Luke! It is very easy.

Given `test.hs`

```
module Test (_1_bin_seqs, _2_bin_seqs) where

_1_bin_seqs :: Int -> [[Int]]
_1_bin_seqs n = iterate add_bit [[]] !! n
    where add_bit seqs = [b : seq | seq <- seqs, b <- [-1,1]]

_2_bin_seqs :: Int -> [[Int]]
_2_bin_seqs n = sequence $ replicate n [-1,1]
```

You have to run

```
$ ghc test.hs -fforce-recomp -O2 -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all
```

- `-fforce-recomp` - rebuild always
- `-O2` - preferred optimization level
- `-ddump-simpl` - output core code to stdout
- `-dsuppress-all` - make that ouput readable by a human
- `-ddump-rule-rewrites` - (optional) show what code rewrite rules where used

Commenting module imports you can control what function to coredump. You'll see that GHC converted first version to `iterate` + loop, while second was not so sweet.